# How to get data json from array of the year in array android studio?

Tags: java, json

I have problem when I try to get data from a JSON array in Android Studio.
I want to get data from year 2015, 2016 and 2018 populate them in different textviews.

This is my JSON:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "7",
      "kecamatan": "Blambangan Umpu",
      "year": {
        "2015": {
          "id": "27",
          "value": "60200"
        },
        "2016": {
          "id": "41",
          "value": "61516"
        },
        "2018": {
          "id": "7",
          "value": ""
        }
      },
      "avg": 2.14
    },
```

and this is my mainactivity

```java
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
    // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++) {
        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = o.getString("id");
        String kec = o.getString("kecamatan");
        String avg = o.getString("avg");
        String tahun = o.getString("year");

        // JSONArray array2 = o.getJSONArray("year");
        // for (int j = 0; j<array2.length(); j++) {
        // JSONObject p = array2.getJSONObject(j);
        // String value = p.getString("value");

        ListItem item = new ListItem(id, kec, avg, tahun, avg);
        listItems.add(item);
        // }
    }

    adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you facing? Are there any blockers? Provide some more details..

Comment: what fields you need from `"2015": { "id": "27", "value": "60200" }`?

Comment: @Blogger i want to display data array from year. And i want to extract it become one textview for each data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`year` is a `JSONObject` with `2015,2016 and 2018` as keys and `JSONObject` as values, So get `year JSONObject` and then get keys and values by iterating it

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i<array.length(); i++)   {
   JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
   String id = o.getString("id");
   String kec = o.getString("kecamatan");
   String avg = o.getString("avg");
   JSONObject yearObject = o.JSONObject("year");   //get JSONObject 

   Iterator<String> itr = yearObject.keys();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {

        String year = itr.next(); 
       JSONObject obj = o.get("year");                //2015
        System.out.println(obj.getString("id"));      //27
        System.out.println(obj.getString("value"));   //60200
    }

     //Add required fields into `ListItem`
     ListItem item = new ListItem(id,kec,avg,tahun,avg);
     listItems.add(item);
  }
```

Comment: I get error in the word "next" from code JSONObject obj = o.get(next)

Comment: not working bro :(, i can display it but just 2015 of the year. Can you check my updated answer ? thanks before